# От меня убегают игнорируемые метки

Tags: поддержка, метки, вопросы, игнорируемые-метки

Вопросы, в которых имеются *игнорируемые метки*, в списке выглядят прозрачными. В моем списке игнорируемых меток их довольно много и я на все 100% уверен, что там были (и есть сейчас) такие метки, как [azure](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure), [angularjs](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs) или [asp.net](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net). Но я иногда (вот например, один прецедент был 10 минут назад) получаю вопрос (непрозрачный) с 1 меткой, которую ранее обязательно должен был добавить в список игнорируемых.

В связи с чем **вопрос**: может, на SO имеется механизм, который время от времени выкидывает метку из списка игнорируемых или иногда сбоит алгоритм фильтрации?
Может кто-то сталкивался с подобным явлением?

Comment: Может у этого вопроса менялись метки кем-то, тогда возможно такое явления как кэш.