# Игнорируемые метки не добавляются

Tags: дефект, игнорируемые-метки

Не знаю, у одного ли у меня проблема с метками или нет, но суть в том, что у меня есть **игнорируемые метки**, которые **скрываются** (рисунок 1)
[image: Метки до внесения (добавления) исключений]

Я заметил, что они у меня не полные, т.е. список игнорируемых меток не полный, как изначально я заносил метки. Их было больше. Далее, на рисунке 2, я заношу снова игнорируемые метки.

[image: Занесение игнорируемых меток]

Но после того, как я нажимаю "добавить", у меня всплывают все метки, которые я вводил ранее (рисунок 3)

[image: Метки, добавленные ранее]

Но после обновления страницы они снова отображаются как на рисунке 1 и, соответственно, не игнорируются ранее введенные. Браузер обновлен до последней версии, кэш и куки чистил. Ранее [подобный вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6481/%D0%9E%D1%82-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F-%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82-%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8) был задан.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так вы на многоточие нажмите, и отобразятся остальные метки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: О господи. У меня такой экран на ноутбуке, и в принципе я не видел это троеточие... При нажатии на "править" не высвечивался список, вот и подумал, что баг. Вопрос закрыть или даже удалить можно. Довольно глупо получилось.

Comment: @KrasPvP на самом деле, как по мне, тут косяк в плане UX.